# Mat Autocomplete is returning empty string in console.log Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

I have a matautrocomplete component and it has the formControl attribute. As i am trying to get the valuse of the input fields after the user has selected the valuse it is returning empty string. How can i get the the value on the form submit.

TEMPLATE file

```
 <mat-form-field class="" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Available City</mat-label>
    <input matInput class="input-text" placeholder="start typing" [matAutocomplete]="location" value="{{locvaluse}}" [formControl]="locationFormControl">
    <mat-autocomplete #location="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" >
      <mat-option *ngFor="let location of filteredOptions | async" [value]="location">
              {{ location.name}}
      </mat-option>
     </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
```

TS File

```
  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.adverForm.controls.locationFormControl.value);
  }
```

Filtering options

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.filteredOptions = this.locationFormControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.locations.slice())
      );
  }

  displayFn(location: LocationTypes): string {
    this.locvaluse = location && location.name ? location.name : '';
    return this.locvaluse
    }

  private _filter(name: string): LocationTypes[] {
    const filterValue = name.toLowerCase();

    return this.locations.filter(location => location.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using `[formGroup]="adverForm"` then you should use `formControlName="locationFormControl"`.

Comment: if not using `[formGroup]` you should use `get locationFormControl() { return this.adverForm.get('locationFormControl');}` in your component.

Comment: @JsNgian thank you for your reply, I tried to use formControlName as i am using reactive forms. As soon as i do that the filtering system stops working when the user is tryping.

Comment: `filteredOptions` can you how you are filtering?

Comment: @JsNgian  I have implimented the autocomplete using the mataurocomplet method. Will add a codesnippit to the question.

Comment: @JsNgian im not sure ifim doing anything wrong in there.

Comment: `map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),` what is this condition for?
What is the value of `location` variable

Comment: @JsNgian   i go that for the autocomplete documentation in the Angilar website. at what point do you need the location value?